# Screw Modifier doesn't work (faces of solid are broken???)

Tags: modifiers, screw-modifier

I'm new to Blender and I have the problem that when I let an object be screwn (?) the face at the roof is just a hole (or something like that). How do I fix this?

I have used an unedited cube and an edited cube. It doesn't work for .stl files and also for cubes which were directly generated in Blender.

You can download the files here:
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1qwKV8pc6Wd7gUdNe35U0Nk8RD2unsFk3?usp=sharing

[image: none]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just left one face, remove all except one:

[image]

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/screw.html

You can fill the caps using this Geometry nodes setup:

[image]

Comment: Ah, thank You very much!
But if I do it like this I don't have a closed roof

Comment: @FrozrOne define "roof".

Comment: @crantisz Thank You very much!!